# Inconsistent Selenium Grid Errors

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid

I am running tests on Selenium grid - usually 5 machines running tests in parallel. I am getting some odd errors that aren't consistent. For example, one of my tests with about 600 iterations will finish with 0-50 of the 3 errors below. The number is different every time I run it. For each exception, the line it fails on is always the same.

1. `org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException:
   Command duration or timeout: 65.91 seconds
   com.web.test.library.BaseTest.openUrl(BaseTest.java:45)`

   Line #45 in BaseTest: `remoteDriver.get(url);`
2. `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Read timed out
   Command duration or timeout: 134.11 seconds
   com.web.test.utility.DriverFactory.generateDriver(DriverFactory.java:46)`

   Line #46 in DriverFactory: `WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver("my hub url here", capabilities);`
3. `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port 7054 within 45000 ms
   com.web.test.utility.DriverFactory.generateDriver(DriverFactory.java:46)`

   Line #46 in DriverFactory: `WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver("my hub url here", capabilities);`

When I search for these errors online the fixes only help when this error is stopping every test. I can't find anything when it happens inconsistently like this. For example, the fix I found for #1 requires editing the host file. I don't think that is the problem in my case since it works ~95% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you are doing parallel testing using multiple threads.

If that is the case, I would recommend looking at [ThreadGuard](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ThreadGuard.html).  It's a lightweight solution to make Webdriver thread safe.

If that doesn't work, then I imagine you are running into a networking overload problem (you are trying to do too many outgoing connections).  How to fix such a problem, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan. I will check that out. You are correct that I am running tests in parallel with multiple threads.

Comment: @l3v I know long time has past since then, but any chance that you've solved the problem? IS it possible for you to share the solution a little bit?

Comment: @YAAK I do not have a solution. I don't remember how I got rid of it. If I recall, I think this was happening with FirefoxDriver and I began to mostly use ChromeDriver. I also use ThreadGuard as mentioned above.